# Nome do atributo dinâmico em Post Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

De que forma posso usar o dado da variável type como titulo/name do atributo que será passado no POST?

O type é dinâmico pois é de fato o nome da coluna no banco de dados.

```
$('body').on('click', '.setCompany', function(e){
        var type = $('.modal.in').attr('data-type')
        var id = $(this).attr('id')

        $.post("/admin/purchase_orders_groups/8",
            { ${type}: id, _method: 'PUT' }
        )
})
```

Comment: isso soa meio estranho.. no lado server você recebe um objeto sem saber o nome da propriedade? não seria mais fácil receber um par "nome/valor"? assim `var postData = { nome: type, valor: id }`

Comment: Posso fazer assim também, só implica em mais código no backend. Estou realmente tentando simplificar.
Do lado do servidor sim, há um validator barrando o que não for viável e aceitando o que for ideal.

Comment: entendo e realmente tem que mudar o backend, mas nem sempre o simplificar fica mais simples e claro pra entender. Neste exemplo que dei, qualquer um que ler o código vai saber o que está sendo enviado e recebido

Comment: Concordo plenamente, inclusive, se houver alguma forma de tornar o nome do elemento dinâmico, ficaria ainda mais simples de entender. Considere que poderia ser  `{ $type = id }`
Seria fácil também

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assim acho que resolve seu problema:

```js
var type = 'AlgumaCoisa';
var id   = 'AlgumValor';

var x = { [`${type }`]: id, _method: 'PUT' };
console.log(x);
```

Isso funciona no **Ecmascript 6**

Comment: Sensacional, é exatamente isso que pensei. Mas não soube exatamente como procurar isso. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Eu tinha visto algo parecido aqui nos código q alguém fez, tb não sabia como procurar rs